# How do I get input out of a class and into the main script

Tags: python, list, class, input, python-3.x

I can't get any longer with the program I'm working on and have a question. I'll post my code first.

My class code looks like this:

```
import requests
import json

class requestNew:

    def __init__(self):
        self.countrychoice = []
        self.citychoice = []

    def countryChoice(self):
        countryc = input("Enter which country your city is in(in english): ")
        self.countrychoice.append(countryc)

    def cityChoice(self):
        cityc = input("Enter the name of the city: ")
        self.citychoice.append(cityc)
```

as you can see I have input in `def countryChoice(self):` and in `def cityChoice(self):`
I want it out of the class functions and into the main script.

This is how the relevant part of my main script looks like at the moment:

```
from requestnew import requestNew


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Introducion"""
    print ("\nThis program lets you see a weather forecast for your choosen city.")
    rq = requestNew()


    while True:
        print("\nWhen you have typed in country and city, press 3 in the menu to see the weather forecast for your choice.\n")
        menu = input("\nPress 1 for country\nPress 2 for city\nPress 3 to see forecast\nPress 4 to exit\n")
        if menu == "1":
            rq.countryChoice()
        elif menu == "2":
            rq.cityChoice()
```

At this moment my mainscript just calls the class functions and they do the work with input. But how do I get the input out from the class and into the mainscript.

As you can see in my class the input appends to a list in:

```
def countryChoice(self):
    countryc = input("Enter which country your city is in(in english): ")
    self.countrychoice.append(countryc) #Here
```

And if I get the input in my main-script, is it even possible to still get the input to append to the `self.countrychoice.append(countryc)` in my class? I need to be able to do it because later in my class I'm using the list-items like this:

```
def forecastRequest(self):
    r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + self.countrychoice[-1] + "/" + self.citychoice[-1] + ".json")
    self.data = r.json()
```

As you can see in the code above I'm using the list-items `self.countrychoice[-1] + "/" + self.citychoice[-1]`, this is to get the right adress for my api.

So my question is, how do I get the input out of the class and into my main script without messing up the appending to the list? If it's even possible.

Sorry if anything is poorly explained or written. It's really confusing for me since I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access attributes of an object from outside, you do it the same way as from inside, except with the object variable instead of `self`.

For example, inside the class, you do this:

```
self.countrychoice[-1] + "/" + self.citychoice[-1]
```

Outside the class, with the instance stored in `rq`, you do this:

```
rq.countrychoice[-1] + "/" + rq.citychoice[-1]
```

And similarly, after you call `rq.forecastRequest()`, you can access the data as `rq.data`. So, you can write something like this:

```
while True:
    print("\nWhen you have typed in country and city, press 3 in the menu to see the weather forecast for your choice.\n")
    menu = input("\nPress 1 for country\nPress 2 for city\nPress 3 to see forecast\nPress 4 to exit\n")
    if menu == "1":
        rq.countryChoice()
    elif menu == "2":
        rq.cityChoice()
    elif menu == "3":
        rq.forecastChoice()
        for line in rq.data.splitlines():
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a value from the methods:

```
def countryChoice(self):
    countryc = input("Enter which country your city is in(in english): ")
    self.countrychoice.append(countryc)
    return countryc
```

In the main script you can then get the country choice:

```
countryChoice = rq.countryChoice()
```

Furthermore you can still obtain all the values from the list by accessing `rq.countrychoice`. The same reasoning applies to `cityChoice` and `rq.citychoice`.